# Title on mapfieldScreen in blackeberry is not visible

Tags: blackberry, tabs, titlebar, blackberry-maps, labelfield

[image]

I am creating a map app. in which i am using mapfield. on the MapFieldScreen I am trying to add Title and also creating tabs but these two things are not visible. instead there is just gray color on these two places..

Here is my code.

```
class MapFieldScreen extends MainScreen
{ 
MapFieldScreen()
{   
    title= new LabelField("My Trip",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER|LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
    {
       protected void layout(int width,int height)
       {
            setExtent(UIConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH, getFont().getHeight()*2);
       }
       public void paint(Graphics g)
        { 
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);             
            g.drawText(label,UIConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH*2/5,getFont().getHeight()/2);  
            super.paint(g); 
        }
    };
    setTitle(title);    
    mLoc= Bitmap.getBitmapResource(UIConstants.STOP);
    mmMapField = new MapField();

    add(mMapField);

}
}
```

Comment: There is no tab in above sample code, only title and map.

Comment: ya.. actually i am extending the tab class. even that titlebar is also not comming.

Comment: I have pasted this code in one of my `MainScreen`, and the title is working (though I'm not sure why you call `super.paint()` if you are doing the paint by yourself). And I got gray color on map.

Comment: Actually this super.paint is for some gradient effect which I want. I am creating that gardient effect also.. for this code its not required.

Comment: did you test the version, setTitle("String")?

Answer (score 0):

You can check follwing code:

```java
LabelField title = new LabelField("My Trip") {
    int _width = Display.getWidth();
    int _height = getFont().getHeight() * 2;

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(_width, _height);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int xText = (_width - getFont().getAdvance(getText())) / 2;
        int yText = (_height - getFont().getHeight()) / 2;
        graphics.drawText(getText(), xText, yText);
    }
};

setTitle(title);
```

Comment: without mapfield my code is working f9. i am using this same code with other screen but its not working for the mapfields.